# Building intermediate incremental model from base incremental models

Tags: dbt

I have below use case for creating intermediate model and output models from 2 or more base incremental models.

Currently, I am thinking of an incremental approach for join.
Approach:

1. Do a complete join in the first run
2. Incrementally: Table 1 joins (new changes of Table 2) UNION ALL (new changes of Table 1) joins Table 2
3. Merge the above result into already joined table.

Is there any better approach?